# Solr - sorted results based on query params

Tags: solr

I have limited set of results, where I'm expecting sorted order of the docs based on query I have provided.

**For example:** I have 4 docs with id field as 1,2,3,4.
Now, when I query the Solr as

> `q=id:(3+OR+2+OR+1+OR+4)`

then I'm expecting the order of results as 3,2,1,4 irrespective of the score of the doc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

then you need to provide a custom sort param, and there set the sort you explicitly want:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id:(3+OR+2+OR+1+OR+4)&sort=if(eq(id,3),10,if(eq(id,2),8,if(eq(id,1),4,0))) desc
```

The syntax is ugly, but it is just comparing the id to the different values and giving them decreasing values. You might want to look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries to see if you find some other function combination that is easier on the eyes.

Comment: I'm getting this error "sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index"

Comment: copy here the url of your query

Comment: well in your examples the id looked like an int, so I used the functions that work on numbers. But the same can be achieved with strings as well, just look at all function queries and tweak the formula until you get what you need